# Unexpected token in external JSON error

Tags: javascript, json

I have been asked to use external json file to change data & for data i did something like this

script>

```
    function loadJSON(callback) {

        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', 'linkto.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                callback(xobj.responseText);
              }
        };
        xobj.send(null);
     }


function init() {
 loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
 });
}


     //More Code
```

My Json file looks something like this (Note this is an external JSON file, not on server, just a normal json file)

```
{
    "lae":[
        {
            "lang":"English"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Turkish"
        }
    ],
    "curn":[
        {
            "curr" : "dollar"
        },

        {
            "curr" : "euro"
        }
    ],
    "gnamd":[
        {
            "gname":"poker"
        },
        {
            "gname":"slot"
        }
    ],
    "freeplay": "false"

}
```

But this is throwing an unexpected error here

```
  "lae" : [
```

[Question]: Any Idea what I might be doing wrong or what could be causing this error?

Comment: Post the exact error please

Comment: The JSON seems to be valid. Not sure why the error occurs. Share a screenshot perhaps ?

Comment: please share the logs files - my assumption based on the information is that this is blowing up on     var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response); , but can't tell because we need more information.

Comment: it seems work fine i tried it with same details i think you have to add more details